# How to order by two related values in a table

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

In MySQL database I have a table:

```
+----+---------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+  
| id | file_id | file_name         | is_complementary | complementary_for |  
+----+---------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+  
| 55 |      52 | photo.png         |                0 |              NULL |  
| 56 |      53 | photo_edit.png    |                1 |                52 |  
| 57 |      54 | card.png          |                0 |              NULL |  
| 58 |      55 | card_edit.png     |                1 |                54 |  
| 59 |      56 | photo_edit_2.png  |                1 |                52 |  
+----+---------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Table has records of "original" files (`file_id`) and their edited copies ("complementary files"). If file is original `is_complementary` value of such file is `0`, and if not `is_complementary` value is `1` and `complementary_for` value indicates which `file_id` it refers to.

How to sort this table in a way that if original file is displayed, rows right after that are complementary files for that displayed original file?  My goal is to get result like this:

```
+----+---------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+ 
| id | file_id | file_name         | is_complementary | complementary_for | 
+----+---------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+ 
| 55 |      52 | photo.png         |                0 |              NULL | 
| 56 |      53 | photo_edit.png    |                1 |                52 | 
| 59 |      56 | photo_edit_2.png  |                1 |                52 | 
| 57 |      54 | card.png          |                0 |              NULL | 
| 58 |      55 | card_edit.png     |                1 |                54 | 
+----+---------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand. I don't see the pattern in your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM <put table name here>
 ORDER BY IF(is_complimentary = 0, file_id, complimentary_for), is_complimentary
```

The first ordering criterion uses the ID of the original file; an original file and all its complimentary files land next to each other in the sorted result. The second criterion puts the original file before its complimentary files. You can add `file_id` to get the complimentary files sorted by their creation order (or other criterion, like `file_name`).

However, be aware that such ordering cannot use an index and is slow on large tables.